cookies are not being set on browser Django, I have a function where cookies work and the other doesn't, why?
I'm making a webapp in Django and Electron using websockets and I wanted to insert one of the socket responses into the user's cookies, but unfortunately I don't know why but they are not being inserted, here is an example of what I am doing:
in the response.cookies printout something like this appears: Cookies defined in the response: Set-Cookie: image_data="pls work"; expires=Tue, 21 May 2024 16:22:33 GMT; Max-Age=3600; Path=/
here is my code if you have any ideas or need any part of the code I will provide it, thank you.
code:
@csrf_exempt
def process_screenshot(request):
    call = identificador_unico(request)
    print("call:", call)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image_content = request.POST.get('image_content')
        
        if image_content:
            print("String em base64 recebida com sucesso.")
            try:
                # Decodifica a string em base64 para obter os dados binários da imagem
                image_data = base64.b64decode(image_content)
                print("base64", image_data[:20])
                
                # Salva os dados binários da imagem em um arquivo
                file_path = 'frames/screenshot.jpg'
                with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(image_data)
                
                image_content = "pls work"
                # Salva image_data nos cookies
                response = JsonResponse({'message': 'Imagem processada com sucesso'})
                response.set_cookie('image_data', image_content, max_age=3600,secure=False,samesite=None)  # Expira em 1 hora
                print("Cookies definidos na resposta:", response.cookies)
                
                return response
            except Exception as e:
                # Se ocorrer algum erro ao decodificar a string em base64 ou salvar o arquivo
                print("Erro ao processar imagem:", e)
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Erro ao processar imagem'}, status=500)
        else:
            # Se nenhuma string em base64 for recebida
            print("Nenhuma string em base64 recebida.")
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Nenhuma string em base64 recebida'}, status=400)
    else:
        # Se a solicitação não for do tipo POST
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Método não permitido'}, status=405)

printscreen of cookies on browser:

and i have a code where cookies are being inserted:
other code
@csrf_exempt
def process_frame(request):
    print("Processando frame...")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        frame_data = request.POST.get('frame_data')
        frame_data = frame_data.split(',')[1]  # Remover o prefixo 'data:image/png;base64,'
        frame_data = base64.b64decode(frame_data)
        frame_data = np.frombuffer(frame_data, dtype=np.uint8)
        frame = cv2.imdecode(frame_data, flags=1)

        cv2.imwrite('frames/CurrentFrame.jpg', frame)
        
        # Agora você pode passar o frame para a função compare_faces()
        result = compare_faces(request, frame)
        print("result:", result)
        if result == None:
            response = JsonResponse({'error': 'Utilizador não encontrado crie um rosto'}, status=400)
        elif isinstance(result, HttpResponseRedirect):
            response = JsonResponse({'message': 'redirecionamento', 'url': result.url})
        else:
            response = JsonResponse({'message': result})

        # Se um UUID foi gerado, defina-o no cookie da resposta
        face_recognition = FaceRecognition(request)
        if face_recognition.uuid is not None:
            print("UUID gerado no processar frame:", face_recognition.uuid)
            response.set_cookie('user_uuid', str(face_recognition.uuid))

        print("response:", response)
        return response
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Método não permitido'}, status=405)

I'm wondering why it doesn't work

There is a problem with the way you are setting Cookie in process_screenshot(). If the SameSite attribute of a Cookie is set to None, it requires a secure context i.e. the Cookie must have a Secure attribute. You are violating that principle here:
response.set_cookie('image_data', image_content, max_age=3600, samesite=None, secure=False)
Change it to this and it will work:
response.set_cookie('image_data', image_content, max_age=3600, samesite=None, secure=True)

thanks for your answer but im using a http website, and secure=True its not only for https websites ?

I’m so sorry for your confusion but this is a named requirement. See MDN.

ok, I already understood from the excerpt "A cookie with the Secure attribute is only sent to the server with an encrypted request over the HTTPS protocol. It's never sent with unsecured HTTP (except on localhost)", but even if I put it that way it still not be inserted, I've even tried with this function and it doesn't insert, I don't understand why:
def identificador_unico(request):      response = HttpResponse("Cookie Set")     cookie_uuid = uuid.uuid4()      response.set_cookie('user_uuid', str(cookie_uuid))       return response

Is that the one that works? You know you said one works and the other doesn’t.

yes, i know, this one i made today, and he dont works too, i dont know why, and the "other code" on the code on the post works

something like, this one work:
response.set_cookie('user_uuid', str(face_recognition.uuid))
but this one no
response.set_cookie('user_uuid', str(cookie_uuid))
why ? no idea, they have the same value and the same name, one insert , and the other one no

Hmm that’s weird.

i know, im trying to solve, but i dont know , if you want to see my other post is here

I have seen it. Gordon answered it correctly. You should add the needed information so that you may get a canonical answer. Add the index view.
